# Program doesn't see Host Header

Tags: go, curl, http-headers

Trying to proxy a request, and I discovered the host header is not being present in the headers received

UPDATE: as pointed out from one of the answers, I might need the Host field, this doesn't change either, host headers are still not present.

code:

```
    request, err := http.ReadRequest(bufio.NewReader(conn))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error reading request", err)
        return
    }

    target, err := net.Dial("tcp", request.URL.Host)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(host)
        log.Println("Error reaching target", err)
    }
    defer target.Close()
```

curl command

```
curl -v localhost:8080
```

Output:

```
   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
>
```

So host header is present in the curl.

Added a debug step to the program to print headers

```
    fmt.Println("Headers:")
    for key, values := range request.Header {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", key, values)
    }
```

Output from program:

```
Headers:
Accept: [*/*]
User-Agent: [curl/7.79.1]
```

Still no presence of Host header

Now I tried passing a host header with curl:

```
curl -v -H 'Host: localhost:3000' localhost:8080
```

Same output, header present in curl but not on the program

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `Host` field of the [`Request`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request) type. From the Godoc:

> // For server requests, Host specifies the host on which the
> // URL is sought. For HTTP/1 (per RFC 7230, section 5.4), this
> // is either the value of the "Host" header or the host name
> // given in the URL itself. For HTTP/2, it is the value of the
> // ":authority" pseudo-header field.
> // It may be of the form "host:port". For international domain
> // names, Host may be in Punycode or Unicode form. Use
> // golang.org/x/net/idna to convert it to either format if
> // needed.
> // To prevent DNS rebinding attacks, server Handlers should
> // validate that the Host header has a value for which the
> // Handler considers itself authoritative. The included
> // ServeMux supports patterns registered to particular host
> // names and thus protects its registered Handlers.
> //
> // For client requests, Host optionally overrides the Host
> // header to send. If empty, the Request.Write method uses
> // the value of URL.Host. Host may contain an international
> // domain name.
> Host string

Comment: Doesn't the program have see the header first? Because the debug steps to print headers, doesn't print the Host. Maybe I'm getting everything wrong.